# Convert String Object to Float Python

Tags: string, python-3.x, casting, int

My code:

```
else:
        revenue2 = revenue
        stripLastLetter = revenue[len(revenue)-1:len(revenue)]

        if stripLastLetter == "B":
            result = revenue2[:-1]
            revNum = float(result.replace(",", ""))
            final = revNum * 1000000000
            newnum = "{:0,.2f}".format(final)
            #print(newnum)
        elif stripLastLetter == "M":
            result = revenue2[:-1]
            revNum = float(result.replace(",", ""))
            final = revNum * 1000000
            newnum = "{:0,.2f}".format(final)
            #print(newnum)
        elif stripLastLetter == "K":
            result = revenue2[:-1]
            revNum = float(result.replace(",", ""))
            final = revNum * 1000
            newnum = "{:0,.2f}".format(final)
            #print(newnum)
        else:
            result = revenue2
            revNum = float(result.replace(",", ""))
            final = revNum
            newnum = "{:0,.2f}".format(final)
            #print(newnum)

        if float(newnum) > 50000000:
            print(ticker.upper()+newnum)
        else:
            None
```

When running, my "newnum" variables look like this: "56,100,000,000.00" but still remain strings.

In my last if-statement, I compare newnum to an int and am drawing an error: "could not convert string to float: '30,270,000,000.00'"

How can I cast newnum to be a float/int object ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your string has commas in it try:

```
newint = float(newnum.replace(',',''))
```

Comment: But my code strips the commas first, converts to a float, then adds the commas back with the .format function. This solution returns a "Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly" error for me

Comment: Could you print the string that you are trying to convert like 'print(newnum)'

Comment: Yes, that prints fine

Comment: But what does it print... Did you try my solution?
It would appear that you are adding commas back into the string with the format function (e.g. "{:0,.2f}")

Comment: Yes, I am adding commas back, but the format function does not change the type of the object. In other words, adding the commas with the .format function still keeps the object type as a float.

Comment: The 'Type' of newnum is string, Youre going to need to strip the commas before you turn it into a float. Just change "if float(newnum) > 50000000:" to "if float(newnum.replace(',','')) > 50000000:" and check if it works.